# Another Discovery of Wind in the Studio

Tags: wind, techniques, sound-design

It's Sunday.

Here's another recording I just did.

This time I took the same Kleenex box I used before and without any air flow, I stuck it on the ground, placed the hole right next to the U87 and rubbed the top of the box with my finger in slow motions, making the nuances of the wind you hear here:

http://soundcloud.com/utopiarc/wind-sample-2

[soundcloud]utopiarc/wind-sample-2[/soundcloud]

The first section is the raw recording, and the second section is with a bit of reverb added.

Comment: Nice. Loving your experimentation.

Comment: Sounds great, might try it myself with different objects :)

Comment: Wow. Sounds fantastic. Gotta try this for myself. 

Comment: This is great. It's a nice soft base layer for a cool wind sound!

Comment: Sweet! This will come in handy for my new project, i need to experiment with this.

Comment: Is this raw, or did you process it a bit?

Comment: It sounds like I'm standing at the gaping maw of a mystic/haunted cave

Answer (score 1):

wow, sounds great! PROPS!